# Adding Headers to AWS API Gateway Response using Chalice

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, amazon-cognito, custom-headers, chalice

My use-case requires my app to return CORS headers when error response is 401.

This functionality was added by AWS last year ([See this](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2017/06/amazon-api-gateway-enables-customization-of-error-responses/)). It can be done using Cloudformation and Swagger template but I'm not sure if it's yet possible with Chalice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved my problem by using a python script that adds the CORS headers for 401 response and redeploys the API. This redeploying of API takes a second or two since it doesn't have to deploy all Lambdas like Chalice.

**deploy.sh**

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

cd services
A="$(chalice deploy --stage $1)"
cd ..
python update_api_response_headers.py "$A" "$1"
```

**update_api_response_headers.py**

```
import boto3
import sys
import re

if len(sys.argv) != 3:
    print("usage: python script.py <CHALICE_DEPLOYMENT_RESULT> <STAGE>")
    exit()

search = re.search('URL: https:\\/\\/([a-zA-Z0-9]+).+', sys.argv[1])
api_id = search.group(1)
print(api_id)
if not api_id:
    print(sys.argv[1])
    exit()
client = boto3.client('apigateway')

response = client.put_gateway_response(
    restApiId=api_id,
    responseType='UNAUTHORIZED',
    statusCode='401',
    responseParameters={
        "gatewayresponse.header.Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "'*'",
        "gatewayresponse.header.Access-Control-Allow-Headers": "'*'"
    }
)
response = client.create_deployment(
    restApiId=api_id,
    stageName=sys.argv[2])

print(sys.argv[1])
```

Services folder contains my chalice app. **deploy.sh** and **update_api_response_headers.py** are placed one level above the chalice app. To deploy the app I simply have to use:

```
./deploy.sh stage_name
```